# Error con php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, artisan

Estoy usando xampp, php 7.1.1, laravel 5.5, MySQL(MariaDB), todo en un entorno windows.

cuando trato de establecer la migración inicial me da la siguiente respuesta

```
$ php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

In Connection.php line 458:
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Como resultado me crea efectivamente la tabla de usuarios (users) y otra "migrations" pero no crea la table de "password reset"

Que me estoy perdiendo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este es un error bastante común, investigando un poco he encontrado [este artículo donde](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error) explica el porqué de ese fallo.

Lo que sucede es que Laravel por defecto trabaja en 'utf8mb4' y si estás usando MySQL > 5.7.7 o MariaDB > 10.2.2 debes especificar el tamaño por defecto de las cadenas.

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir en AppServiceProvider esto:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Es un problema bastante frecuente. Hace tiempo que no toco laravel en profundidad, pero siempre me pasaba esto mismo que a ti te ocurre.

**EDIT**

Tambien he encontrado esto mismo en la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-indexes), donde ellos mismos te dicen que escribas lo que te acabo de poner arriba

Comment: Este error se resuelve así o indicando la longitud de la cadena en la migración o usando una versión más reciente de MySQL

Comment: Ahh pues voy a revisar esos artículos .. pero igual tu sugerencia no avanzó... ahora ni siquiera creó las tablas .. la respuesta en este caso fue ... `D:\WWW\laravel>php artisan migrate

In AppServiceProvider.php line 16:

  Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found
` la versión de MariaDb que estoy usando es la 10.1.21

Comment: @Aprendiz eso es cierto, aunque es precisamente en la documentación de Laravel donde te dicen que esto se debe hacer si se usa una version de MySQL o MariaDB *superiores* a las citadas en la respuesta.

Comment: @elapez Prueba a hacer un `composer dump-autoload` despues de haber hecho los cambios. Si no, dime y veremos la forma de ayudarte.

Comment: Bueno intenté hacer el dump-autoload sugerido pero me da un error.. `Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In AppServiceProvider.php line 16:

  Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
`

Comment: y el error es precisamente en la línea añadida a AppServiceProvider `Schema::defaultStringLength(191);`

Comment: está importado `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` al principio de AppServiceProvider? La traza dice que no encuentra esa clase.

Fíjate que en el fichero hay dos cambios, el añadido del import y el set del defaultStringLength a Schema